# DatePicker SwiftUI - Missing date

Tags: swift, swiftui, uidatepicker

I'm trying to create a form with DatePicker , but can't get it to write on firebase.
I did convert datapicker value into string, but can't understand why in firebase appears date ""

Do I need to create a public var with that value?

Here's my code so far

**Register View** - I get the value here

```
 DatePicker("Start Date ", selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
```

**Details View** - Crunch it

```
var anive = Date()

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long
return formatter
 }()


 }

 extension DetalhesRegisto {

 static var new: DetalhesRegisto{
 DetalhesRegisto(email: "", password: "", nome: "", apelido: "", ocupação: "",      anive: "\(anive, formatter: dateFormatter)")
}
}
```

**Service View**

```
var anive = Date()
}

case anive

let values = [chavesregisto.anive.rawValue: details.anive] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: Bom dia e bem-vindo (greetings). It is a little bit hard to understand how your code works, there are some "holes" and you should post the output that comes when printing the birthday variable (anive). But one thing I can anticipate: `\(anive, formatter: dateFormatter)` is not good to write to firebase, to turn it into a string you need to use `dateFormatter.string(from: anive)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert `Date()` value for `Timestamp()`

First import -> `import FirebaseFirestore`

Then try to pass date value like:

```
let creationDate = Date() // Your date picker value
let firestoreData: [String: Any] = ["creationDate": Timestamp(date: creationDate)]
```